# What are some tips on translating Spanish when reading

Tags: traducción

I read my Spanish/English Bible daily. I have found that it is very difficult to attempt literal English translations of Spanish.  An example of the types of sentences I **do not** have trouble with would be this one:

```
Dios, en el principio, creó los cielos y la tierra.
```

I would translate this in English attempting a literal translation first:  "God, in the beginning, (he) created (those, the) heavens and the land (earth)."

I **do have trouble** with these types of sentences.

```
Por ejemplo, nunca habría sabido yo lo que es codiciar si la ley no hubiera dicho: «No codicies.»
```

I read it this way: "For example (not, nothing, no one)  (having, had) (known) I that which is codified if the law no had said, 'No code (codification, letter of the law)'".

From there I attempt to reform it like this:

"For example, I would have not know what is in the law if the law did not say "No law".

Obviously I'm close but just having a hard time with how to interpret.  In English we don't think like this "not having known I".  Do I need to read it as it is and learn how to think in Spanish to become fluent?

Comment: We actually *do* order sentences like that in English sometimes, but in speech.  *Well, having gone to the store — John, I mean — we'll be able to drink tonight*.  Or, actually just in books, "blah blah *said John*".  Just think of it like poetry where English allows lots of flexibility in word order.

Comment: Yes we do on occasion (or even often) when reporting things.  We call them (if I remember correctly) introductory adverbial clause. For example in a technical report I may say "Having tested all the permutations of the particular thing, the results were this"...

Comment: The first tip is that both the English and Spanish Bibles are translations (or in some cases paraphrases) of the original texts in Greek or Hebrew.

Comment: 'Codiciar' does not mean 'to code', but 'to covet'. Thus, 'no codiciarás' means 'you shall not covet' (or 'thou shalt not covet' in usual Bible English).

Comment: Don't understand moderators closing this. It was understandable for two years with many excellent respones. Maybe you need more education.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely, you can't go with literal translations. Think that the very first thing that you may learn how to say in a different language are basic sentences like

> **Cómo** te llamas? / **What** is your name?

And as you probably already know in Spanish we don't say "**Qué** (what) is your name" nor in English you ask "**How** are you named?". Think that there are even regional differences (Spanish spoken in Spain differs slightly from the one spoken in Mexico, as the British English differs form the one spoken in the U.S. or Australia). Never go literal, try to understand the message and rephrase.

Probably there is no single path to fluency, but I would advise lots of practice (study, read, dare to speak even if you make mistakes, put yourself out of the "confort zone",...) and "do as Romans do", meaning, when speaking, try to sound like what you hear from natives.

One thing that might be giving you trouble with that sentence is "codicies", which is a conjugation of the verb "codiciar". ["Codiciar"](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=eb8b3rUYlDXX2YhOTl7Z) means wanting someone else's belongings (*Thou shall not covet*). The verb conjugation is *subjuntive*, which is a pain for those learning Spanish. So a more accurate translation would be

> For example, I would have not know what is in the law if the law did not say "Don't covet".

Comment: Well, you can do a literal "What is your name?" with "¿Cuál es tu nombre?" :-)

Comment: O sea, [*“por donde fueres, haz lo que vieres.”*](https://books.google.com/books?id=4rIsSFfBAh8C&pg=PA348&lpg=PA348&dq=por+donde+fueres+haz+lo+que+vieres&source=bl&ots=A3eVGjNZJQ&sig=f8QdOHkzbmp7iK1sKBDiz_SBEhM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=w1QEVcHkLcSxggTUyYOwCA&ved=0CFoQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=por%20donde%20fueres%20haz%20lo%20que%20vieres&f=false) :)

Comment: Thanks Diego...  When a Spanish speaking person says "Como te llamas" what do they think.  Do they think "How are you called?" or "What is your name"  While I don't really want to be literal I do want to think (without translating to English) as the Spanish speaker thinks.  I'm finding this a must when considering the "Introductory adverbial phrase" as mentioned above because I see Spanish very much uses that pattern, the pattern of introduction first then to whom or what it affects.

Comment: @JohnPeters They don’t think either of those things: they think just what they’ve said, which was *¿Cómo te llamas?* I strongly advise you **not** to try to translate in your head when reading or listening. That really isn’t a very good way to process language: it will slow you down horribly, not to mention quite a few other problems.

Answer (score 2):

In the case you give, "codicia" means covetousness, and "codicieis" means "you (plural) covet". Obviously related words, although one is a noun and the other a verb.

I have a parallel Bible, that has English on one side and Spanish on the other. It has served me very, very well. In case of doubt, I just glance over to the other side.

You are going to have serious problems if you think that Spanish has the same rules as English, only with Spanish words.  There are many places where the constructions are just not the same.  To name just one example among thousands, a double negative doesn't mean the same thing in Spanish as it does in English.  It means nearly the opposite.

Comment: Walter; thanks for response, yes I've dialed into the double negative and have adjusted to it.  I also realize that Spanish does have different rules, which are communicated in the words.  The first step is to understand the word, I'm gaining a lot of word comprehension, but don't know the rules too well yet.  I thought it best to focus on word meanings first.  Maybe this is why I'm having difficulty.  I must say though that Spanish appears to be way more descriptive than English in a general sense because so much of it "goes to" something.  Vamos a ver!  etc...It action oriented.

Answer (score 1):

To translate effectively, one must read the sentence(s), understand their underlying literal meaning... or rhetorical/abstract meanings... and then think of how to express that idea in English.

Comment: Yes very well said.  I can see how translation is a different aspect than just understanding one or the other.  Being able to translate is like running meanings through mental filters to rearrange structure.  I think I know understand when hearing an interpreter why there is a delay, as they have to get the meaning and say it in a different way.  That process is probably what I'm doing now, trying to make sense in English of Spanish structure and rules which is a bit more complicated than just understanding words.